# Rspec multiple controllers with one common authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Hello guys i have a lot of controller test for an API in different files inside spec/controller folder. For each of those specs i have a

```
before do
  authenticate_user(user, role)
end
```

This is spec´s time consuming because i have to create a User and a Role for every test. I would like to have this same helper at an upper level in order to execute all my controllers test under the same authentication.

does anyone has an idea of who to achieve this?

Stubing this is also a choice but there is a lot of logic under the user that may be difficult and time consuming.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `before(:suite)` or `before(:all)` to prevent multiple calls to this method, e.g.

```
before(:suite) do
  authenticate_user(user, role)
end
```

Also you can locate it at `spec/support/sign_in_helper.rb`, like:

```
module SignInHelper
  def sign_in
    before(:suite) do
      authenticate_user(user, role)
    end 
  end
end
```

and use it at `spec_helper`, like:

```
require 'spec/support/sign_in_helper'
extend SignInHelper
```

After that you'll be able to use it like macros in your controller specs at top-level.